# Hololens / MRTK UIRaycastCamera spins

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I'm trying to do the official tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/mr-learning-base-01

Whenever I try to "play" the scene, the camera rotates.
A "UIRaycastCamera" is created and it is always rotated.

It looks like there's always an input even though I'm not doing anything.
How can this be turned off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: A PS4 controller was connected to the pc. The controller caused this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I found a virtual joystick in my device manager. so I just disabled it and everything is right now.